# "A later version of Microsoft SQL Server Compact is already installed"

Tags: sql-server-ce, sql-server-ce-4

I managed to include, and deploy to Azure websites, SQL Server Compact 4.0 in a MVC project by using Nuget.

I then try to install Microsoft SQL Server Compact 4.0 on my PC via this [link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-sg/download/confirmation.aspx?id=17876).  But it couldn't proceed with:

> A later version of Microosft SQL Server Compact is already installed.

I had only installed SQL Server Express 2016 earlier. I searched and could not find any SQL Server Compact on my PC. What/where is that earlier version the message is refering to? Does it have something like SSMS?

My aim is to be able to make interactive queries on a CE database, create some tables, etc.

Comment: Try this (newer) download (version 4.0 SP1)  : https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30709

Comment: Thanks. The version that was "already installed" on my PC is 4.0 SP1. I didn't install it myself. Could this have been done by the Nuget process? Anyway, what I want is to be able to do some queries *à la* SSMS. What software/tool would allow me to do that?

Comment: @ErikEJ I saw your blog on tools to manage SQL CE. So I installed Webmatrix 3. But I still don't know which tool or component can open my sdf file.

Comment: My SQL Server Compact Toolbox (free VS extension)

Comment: It was probably installed by Visual Studio